# Memory leaks from libsystem_c.dylib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

These are the only leaks i have after some heavy usage:
[image]

The only responsible thing here is `UIScrollView` - which may come from any table in my app.
I have only one custom `UIScrollView`. Here is the only thing I do with my scroll view:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 40+height);
```

I also have one `UIWebView`, which also have a `UIScrollView`.
Should I worry about those leaks? As you can see they go up to 4KB, and with more time of usage, they may use up even more!
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known bug in 5.1 and 5.1.1 and will be fixed in a future release.

I'm not sure I can quote anything from the Apple developer forums, but if you have a developer account, you can find more info [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/661576#661576).

Comment: Thank you! So if i distribute my app with iOS 5.1 SDK, it's going to have this bug on real devices?

Comment: @DevFly Yes, however the impact is (as you can see in the thread) rather limited.